# What is the correct SQLException / spring data exception for missing permissions

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, mysql-connector

I just noticed that when you try to execute a query that does not have required permissions (only tested on a mysql 5.7 database using the mysql-connector-java v8 driver) it is translated to a `org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException`. This is because the mysql driver itself throws a `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException`.

For instance: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: INSERT command denied to user 'myuser'@'127.0.0.1' for table 'mytable'`

Is this correct and/or intentional? I tried to look through the various existing exceptions in both `java.sql` and `org.springframework.jdbc` without finding an obvious alternative candidate.

I looked at the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/5.7/en/server-error-reference.html) for this error:

> Error number: 1142; Symbol: ER_TABLEACCESS_DENIED_ERROR; SQLSTATE:
> 42000
>
> Message: %s command denied to user '%s'@'%s' for table '%s'

As far as I can tell SQLSTATE 42000 is what the driver uses to determine that it is a syntax error.

Comment: I assume it is correct and intentional, since this is how the Spring folks decided to implement it.  What makes you think it's incorrect or unintentional?

Comment: Well, I don't consider a missing table permission to be a syntax error in the query.

Comment: So I dug a little deeper, and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLSTATE) says that SQLSTATE 42000 is _syntax error or access rule violation_ and this is clearly an access rule violation. But I still don't like that it translates into a `BadSqlGrammarException`.

Comment: Does the exception provide any other detail? Can you get the original error using [`getCause()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29)?

Comment: In any case, it feels like you have two choices here: submit a pull request to the Spring team to get this changed, or live with the discomfort of a custom exception type that you don't like.

Comment: There is not really a better exception in the hierarchy for `SQLException` (except maybe using a less-specific exception than `SQLSyntaxErrorException`. Spring JDBC could potentially transform to a different exception with a custom implementation of - IIRC - `SQLExceptionTranslator`.

Comment: Exactly and my hope was that someone from the spring data team was lurking here and could give a hint as to whether this was worth pursuing. I don't mind cooking up a PR but I'm looking for a little guidance since I could not find an appropriate exception in the spring data exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql standard defines the return code for sql statements, kmown as [sqlstate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLSTATE).

Sqlstate 42000 means

> syntax error or access rule violation

Access denied falls into this category, so mysql followed the standard. Java also broadly followed the standard as it reports such errors as syntax error.

Unfortunately, the answer is you cannot use the type of the error to drive your access denied check, you need to look at the error number (1142 in this case).

Comment: Yeah, I have sort of concluded that this is probably just a naming decision taken by the spring team who created `BadSqlGrammarException`, if they had decided to stay closer to the standard they could have named it `BadSqlGrammarOrAccessException`.